# Standard normal distribution tails: Lower bound

Tags: normal-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

I read the book [Foundations of Machine Learning](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Emohri/mlbook/) page 443 and wonder how to prove (D.19), i.e. the following inequality regarding standard normal distribution lower bound:

If N is a random variable following the standard normal distribution, then for $u\ge0$:
$$\mathbb{P}[N\ge u]\ge\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{1-e^{-u^2}})$$

I search in Google and ask GPT-4 but none of them helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of exploration, I find that the above inequality can be proved by the conclusion in [G. Polya (1949)](https://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/math/ucb/text/math_s1_article-05.pdf) and [J. D. Williams (1946)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2236136):
$$\Phi(x)-\frac{1}{2}=\int_{0}^{x}(2\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}dt\le\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-\frac{2}{\pi}x^2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Then, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[N\ge u]& =1-\mathbb{P}[N\le u]\\
&=1-\Phi(u)\\
&\ge\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{1-e^{-\frac{2}{\pi}u^2}})\\
&\ge\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{1-e^{-u^2}})
\end{align}

Here $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}(2\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}dt$